# Supply independent current reference

Tags: mosfet, ltspice

Given is the circuit for supply independent current biasing. What are the spice models that should be used in place of nmos and pmos so thay we get the desired output? It is required that the aspect ratio of M2 should be 'K' times the aspect ratio of M1. Should the 'K'  be obtained by tying the  gate,drain,source of the respective mosfets? 
 [image]

Comment: This all depends on what amount of current this is supposed to operate on, but you could probably use something like the EKV model or any of the models you use with CMOS designs for your particular application...

Comment: I would like to get a constant current of 1uA. Will the mosfet 2n7000 suit for nmos and bs250 suit for pmos ?

Comment: You probably can not use models for the 2N7000 and BS250, because they are not intended to be modified for different W/L ratios. You need to get models for the basic transistors in some integrated circuit manufacturing process. The question of **which** models to use is very broad and is really up to you and your instructor.